# Change IEnumerable dropdown to select enum value instead of number c#

Tags: c#

I have a view model that is connected to an Ienumerable, and a view that is connected to the view model that pulls the Ienumerable as a drop down.  My problem is when I select it, the value is 0,1,2,3 so on and so forth.  How do I get it to pass the value of the Enum BRO,CGS,YHH,POH?

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AllLicenseTypes)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AllLicenseTypes, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**ViewModel**

```
[Display(Name = "License Types")]
public LicenseTypesEnum AllLicenseTypes { get; set; }
```

**IEnumerable**

```
public enum LicenseTypesEnum
{
    BRO,
    CGS,
    YHH,
    POH
}
```

Comment: You have an `enum` listed instead of an `IEnumerable`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, enum != IEnumerable.  They are only tangentially related.

Second, if you want to use that `enum`, what you're looking for is [Enum.GetNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try changing your code to something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "License Types")]
public IEnumerable<string> AllLicenseTypes {
    get {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(LicenseTypesEnum));
    }
}
```

Comment: First, Thank you! I didn't know that.